# How to set fixed window size for Windows Application in cordova phonegap

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins, phonegap

Is there anywhere in the config where I can fix the app size to a certain height/width? And prevent resizing?

Comment: is it just for the layout? then you could just have a div in your body with fixed width and height.

Comment: No, for window.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?